# The best height to mount Kinect on TurtleBot

Tags: kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard TurtleBot mounts the Kinect at <30 cm above the ground. Also there are plates above and below the Kinect. In this case, it is difficult to use the Kinect for object recognition.

Hence I remount it on the top, and also stack up the plates, so the Kinect is now 70 cm above the ground. It seems to have a nice view and can see most objects and people in the office environment. However, it has problems during navigation because of the big blind area in front of its wheel base.

Just wondering, have anyone tried to remount the Kinect at different heights (and angles), and somehow find a most suitable one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59843/the-best-height-to-mount-kinect-on-turtlebot/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on 2013-04-03**:
Great question. Had the same doubt.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-03**:
@Chik Good Question ! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We tried re-mounting it on top like this.

[image: image description]

This position was suitable for us since we had to do both human recognition and navigation. Human gesture recognition was a bit difficult in original position, since plates blocked a part of view. In this position, the problem with navigation was that it was unable to recognize obstacles that lay below it (say, half the height of the robot) during mapping and navigation. But it was not a major issue as the AMCL was robust to overcome it. It was successful for us!

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4